# Multiple Forms on One Page, How to Handle Back Button Behavior?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

So I have 3 forms all on one page, and I have buttons on all those forms to go show or hide previous/next forms. However the back button just takes you to the previous page entirely. Is there a way to have the back button to check if there is a previously completed form and go to that form?

Sorry for the open ended question but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score -1):

Using a database to save your previous walk, will be better trying to,manipulate hiding button using styles and JavaScript will get you in cache mess someday ,,

Please paste your code here for we can see wat u have done,,